# Snippet results can no longer be scrolled while in the snippet editor making it hard to check results

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Note: This is a different issue than [Snippet Editor gets out of sync scrolling and gets very difficult to use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328067/snippet-editor-gets-out-of-sync-scrolling-and-gets-very-difficult-to-use) as that one was about the code editing section which shows different behavior

Steps to repo

1. Click "Show code snippet"
2. Click "Copy snippet to answer"
3. In the new answer click "edit the above snippet"
4. Click "Run"
5. Try to scroll down on the results

This worked before the recent snippet editor update.

Note if you run the snippet outside the editor it's still possible to scroll over the result.

Of course having an extremely long result would be bad but given how short the typical result display area is it's very common for the result to not fit in the given area and require at least a little scrolling.

I've got plenty of snippets that say make a canvas and display an image and/or some text about some computation related to both that needs to be able to scroll to really see what's happening.

```html
<pre>
Scroll down to see the entire thing

A

simple 

snippet

with

several

lines

of

text

that 

don't

fit 

in 

the 

results

without

scrolling

the

longer

it

gets

the 

more 

likely

the

problem

is

worse

because

strange 

things

are

happening

for

example

the 

main 

page

behind

the

code

snippet

edtior

scrolls

when

trying

to 

scroll

any

of

the

panes

in

the

snippet

editor

which 

is

*NOT*

normal

browser

behavior.

Whatever

is

making

both

scroll

should

probably

be

fixed

so

only

the

code

snippet

pane

scrolls.
</pre>
```

Comment: If you really want to indicate that the problem is now gone post an answer (possibly community wiki) explaining that this issue no longer exists and accept it the day after. Having an accepted answer is a more clear indication of a resolution than a sentence at the end of the post in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems mostly fixed as of 2016/09/05.  Both the background and foreground scroll which is still strange but the foreground scrolling at least works which it wasn't back in 2016/07/20