# Weird bug when deleting code in stacksnippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The last times I used a code snipped I noticed that it doesn't work as expected when I want to delete some code. And it seems that the marking (or selecting) doesn't work properly either.

See my example:

[image]
Here it looks like the marked lines are between the real lines.

If I now try to delete this selected part it deletes a totaly different part of the code. See my picture here:
[image]

Here I marked the code which is really deleted and selected, even if the purple marked code was at another position.
[image]

It not a bad bug, just a little bit annoying.
I experienced that it just happens if the code is longer than x and after I scrolled.
It doesn't happen with short code snippets.

EDIT:
Here is a video:

[image]

I tried it in Opera and Chrome, in both browsers its the same.

Comment: A short video might be helpful. Are you at 100% zoom? What browser / OS are you using?

Comment: Ok give me some time, I will make a gif. I usually use Opera (42.0.2393.517)

Comment: @Cerbrus see my update. I made a gif. And I use windows 10, sorry. I also tried it in chrome, but its the same.

Comment: Yes, this happens a lop when there are big scrollbars. Then I use Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V and usually is fixed.

Comment: But just as long as I don't scroll it's fixed. If I scroll again in the snipped its bugged again.

Comment: I experience this bug frequently just by making a new line. I now have a habit of hitting Ctrl+Z after hitting Enter.

Comment: This is closely related to [Snippet Editor gets out of sync scrolling and gets very difficult to use](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328067/4642212). Probably a dupe.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry didn'found that. The only difference is that he trys to insert a char while I try to delete something. But it seems that the error is the same.